What are the chances that the primary oocyte that created me contained atoms of the primary oocyte that created my maternal grandmother?
This isn't so much homework help but more related to personal curiosity. I know that it's generally accepted that all oocytes are created prenatally and once a baby is born, no new oocytes are created. However, even if no new oocytes are created after birth, I would assume that much of the oocytes molecular and even atomic makeup are not the same overtime because of molecular turnover to maintain homeostatic. I assume that there is a very slim chance that the oocyte that created me contains any atoms of the oocyte that created that created my grandmother. Is my assumption correct?
If this isn't the right tag for this type of question please let me know which tag is the right one and I can redirect the question.
Edit: Forgot the word "not" in the third sentence of the paragraph.

Well, sure, there's a statistical chance, but incalculable and probably infinitesimal. I think some of your underlying assumptions are probably incorrect around the molecular turnover; I would have thought degradation of the molecules and loss of these via waste mechanisms rather than recycling, but I know very little about oocytes at that level.

@bob1
I noticed that I forgot a word in the 3rd sentence of my original comment. I meant to say that an oocyte's molecular/atomic makeup is not the same overtime due to molecular turnover to maintain homeostasis. I understand that there is probably no numerical statistical figure to such a question but your answer that the numerical chances are very small supports my assumptions but I wasn't sure if I was missing something. Thanks for the answer!
